# Is there a way to handle conditional drawing in OpenTBS with DOCX?

Tags: docx, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I'm generating a document with conditional drawings in a dynamic table. Let's say I want a share for some rows, a circle for others etc...

I've converted my drawings into pictures and it's working well except the quality is very low after converting the docx it into pdf and printing it.

So my question : Is there a way to handle conditional drawing without converting it into pictures ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a drawing into another with OpenTBS.

But you can make conditional fields that display or delete a drawing.

So the first solution is to add all the possibles shapes in the table row you're taking about.
The shapes should have the Layout Option set to « In Line with Text » ; so that you are sure where the shape is anchored and is actually placed inside the row. 
Then in property Description or Title of the shape you can add a TBS field like:  `[my_block.display_circle;magnet=w:drawing]`.
Such a file will display or delete the shape according to the value of column `display_circle` in the data. See parameter [magnet](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_field_prm_magnet) for more details and options. This can arranged at the PHP side by editing data or using a [ondata](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_prm_ondata) custom function.

Another solution is the use one different row for each possible shapes, and use [conditional section](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_conditional) for blocks.